# Vertical align button middle next to text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to vertically align the button to the middle, so it fits better with the text.
I have tried center-block and text-center without any luck. 
I would like a generic solution so I do not hard-code margin, padding and similar.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhqjumgL/5/
And my code:

```
<h3>FMUs
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the "FMUs" text in an element and `vertical-align` that as well:

```css
h3 > span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h3><span>FMUs</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
    </h3>
```

The `vertical-align` property is relative to siblings, not to the container.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the vertical-align property

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Flexbox`

```css
h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3>FMUs
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
</h3>
```

Comment: This removes the space between the text and the button, how do preserve this?
Ahh @ryachza provided a solution to this!

Answer (score 1):

What may be of interest is to divide the area up further so you have more control:

```
    <h3>
  <div class="container">

  <span class="text"> 
   FMUs

  </span>
  <span class=="button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
  </div>
</h3>
```

And the styles:

```
button,
textarea {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
.text, .button {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

What this allows is a better control over your elements and means that you can specify better position as a result.

The fiddle for you to try is here:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdwzam36/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin-bottom` css-property to `button` element, for example `margin-bottom: 5px;` http://jsfiddle.net/jhqjumgL/26/

Comment: I am looking for a more generic solution